# Extension Method for SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

We have run a conversion tool on an old project which came from VB6.

We're substituting OLEDB with Ado.Net, and RecordSets with SqlDataReaders.

But the converted code always does a `rs.Fields['FirstName']` reference, which I guess would be `rs['FirstName']` with the database reader (where rs is now q SqlDataReader.

Instead of going through all the code, is there a way I could create an extension method on SqlDataReader, which would then make use of "`Fields['FieldName']`"?

This is my current attempt:

```
public static class SqlUtils
    {
        public static object Fields(this SqlDataReader dataReader, string fieldname)
        {
            return dataReader[fieldname];
        }
    }
```

However, this works with:

```
Console.WriteLine(reader.Fields("First").ToString());
```

I need to handle:

```
Console.WriteLine(reader.Fields["First"].ToString());
```

Note, [], not ().

Comment: Perhaps if it is not sealed you could create a custom class inheriting the datareader and create that indexer in your own class. Otherwise I see no options.

Comment: Thanks Silvermind - How would the method look though, to accept a ['fieldname'] parameter? I think this is, what you refered to as an indexer - but I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: This would be the simplest way, cbp, and we may go that route - but my question is also a learning question.

Comment: If you're still interested, take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extension methods are actually just static methods. Since there is no 'static indexer' you cannot have an extension method that uses indexer syntax.

Comment: In principle, C# could theoretically support this syntax, even within the confines of them actually being static methods, but you're correct that C# does not in fact support it.

Answer (score 4):

this static indexer works just dandy...

```
public static string GetDRItem(this IDataReader dr, string colName)
{
    return dr[colName].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Great solution. You should note how to use it (ex: `reader.GetDRItem("First");`)